# Voltage leak when muxing Li-ion cells for voltage measurements?

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, multiplexer, tester, 18650

A disclaimer before I dive in, I am not working with a battery pack. Anytime I refer to Li-Ion cells or 18650s, I am trying to handle each cell as an individual. I am actually avoiding building a battery pack, that would be a problem.

I am working on an automated 18650 tester for evaluating salvaged cells. To do this I thought I would be able to mux 8 cells so I can have a single calibrated multi-meter (only ever in voltmeter mode) doing all the measurements. I am using a CD74HC4067 analog mux to do this.

The issue I ran into while prototyping is that, when all 8 cells are present, the voltage averages (maybe it just is the highest measured) between them, no matter that the mux is set to. In trying to identify the issue, I can measure continuity between test stalls when no cells are present.

Is this a known and observed behaviour when muxing multiple voltage sources? Or is it more likely that there is a problem with the application rather than the theory (Something like a bad breadboard, circuit assembled incorrectly.)

Is something like 8 analog opto-couplers the right direction for a solution? I have some HCNR200's for this.

My mux circuit is very bare bones as seen here.
[image: Schematic of what is connected to the mux]

These photos are of my prototype, I dont expect it to be obvious in a photo but it provides context.
[image: Test Stall from the side]
[image: Test stalls from the front]
[image: Mux circuit deep in spaghetti]

Comment: That shouldn't happen. What logic voltages are bing supplied? Does the multiplexer have power?

Comment: does the MCU share the same ground as the mux?

Comment: I wonder if the leakage current is getting you because the voltmeter is very high impedance.  If you apply a 1 mA load to the output (pin 1, resistor to ground) does the problem go away?

Comment: Sounds like the ground pin on the multiplexer is not connected properly.

Comment: @KevinWhite mux has 5v on vcc pin. Measured logic is max 1v as LOW and min 3.9 HIGH, within the 30% specified on the datasheet.

Comment: @Neil_UK, yes they share a ground, when I measure continuity it shows 80ohms between the ground of the mux and the ground of the MCU.

Comment: @evildemonic I had a 10kohm pull down resistor, the problem persists with a 3.3k

Comment: @Mr.Thinkage - 80 ohms ground continuity sounds rather high. I would hope  it would measure less than 1 ohm.

Comment: @evildemonic - in normal operation at least one channel should be active so the impedance of the meter shouldn't matter.

Comment: @KevinWhite, I agree, but I can't imagine where the resistance is coming from, there is a jumper wire connecting them. I measure 5ohms between any two points on my breadboard gnd rail. and 30ohms (With the power disconnected) between MCU gnd and breadboard gnd. I have a higher quality breadboard that I could swap this out for to see if that helps.